# How to make pagination with json file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get .csv file from user and show as a table. And I need to do pagination for that table. I used for that react-pagination-table. First I get from .csv file from react-file-reader. I did but showing error.
Here is my Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactFileReader from 'react-file-reader';
import { TablePagination } from 'react-pagination-table';

const sampleData = ``;
var result = [];
var data;
const Header = ["Name", "Department", "Designation", "Salary", "Joining Date" 
];

class Main extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state={
  //csvData: null
  data: []
  };
 }

 handleFiles = files => {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
  var csv = reader.result;
  var lines = csv.split("\n");
  console.log(lines.length);
  var headers=lines[0].split(",");
  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
    var obj = {};
    var currentline=lines[i].split(",");
    for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
      obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
    }
    result.push(obj);
  }  
  //return result; //JavaScript object
  result = JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
  console.log(result);
  // Use reader.result
  this.setState({
      //csvData: reader.result
      data: result
  })
  }.bind(this);
reader.readAsText(files[0]);
 }

 render() {
  return(
    <div className="Main">
      <h1>Upload Your CSV File</h1>
        <div>
          <ReactFileReader 
            multipleFiles={false}
            fileTypes={[".csv"]} 
            handleFiles={this.handleFiles}>
            <button className='btn'>Upload</button>
          </ReactFileReader>
          <TablePagination
        title="TablePagination"
        subTitle="Sub Title"
        headers={ Header }
        data={ data }
        columns="Name.Department.Designation.Salary.Joining Date"
        perPageItemCount={ 5 }
        totalCount={ data.length }
        arrayOption={ [["size", 'all', ' ']] }
    />
        </div>
  </div>
  );
 }

 }

 export default Main;
```

Here is my csv file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11vehP4swgVU5tRWB635kmDJd-4ZywGQaZ4kE5C4yaLo

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined This error.